# How to implement login through multiple device in my rails sample app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have done a rails app like twitter. Currently I am managing sessions by storing tokens in a database and the same token as cookie in a browser.

Now I have to implement Multi-device login to the same app. It means that I can logged-in from my computer and from mobile at the same time. Help me to do this.

Note: I have only a single field for my cookie token in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at devise gem it will provide you the https://github.com/plataformatec/devise all the features for session management and authentication